Capture invalid user access
I have an Intranet website in IIS using Windows authentication and have granted an AD security group access to the site.
If a user who is not in the group attempts to access the site, they are prompted to enter their credentials.
I would like to route them to a page to tell them the process to go through to request access to the site.
How do I do that?

If you rely on IIS's built-in authentication (Windows) and authorization, then those users are served by 401.3 responses and the browsers indeed prompt them (the pop up in your words). They should be able to see the actual 401.3 error page if they click Cancel in the prompt (many browsers), and you can customize that error page to tell them where to request access. Or if you want better user experience, develop your own authorization in the web site, and don't use IIS authorization.
